# How do I parse out all HTML tags in a BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble parsing out HTML tags that are in a nested BeautifulSoup object. Here

```
response = requests.get(
'myurl',
headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token},
params=params
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup = json.loads(str(soup))
all_data.extend(soup['data'])
```

But soup['data'] is a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{"_id":"123","tags":[],"user":{"_id":"u1","name":"ASD Na"},"shared":"<p>Personal: Parents </p><p><br/></p><p>KM: </p><p><br/></p>","private":"","created":"2019-01-26T16:54:56.283Z","district":"543543","creator":{"_id":"c432","name":"Cass Man"},"lastModified":"2019-01-26T16:54:56.284Z"},
{"_id":"234","tags":[],"user":{"_id":"u2","name":"Tyler Dass"},"shared":"Hi,<p>It's great to see your clear.</p>","private":"","created":"2019-11-26T15:48:43.314Z","district":"543543","creator":{"_id":"432","name":"John"},"lastModified":"2019-11-26T15:48:43.315Z"}]
```

Even though the tags appear in just the `shared` key, they do appear in multiple fields. How do I access `soup` and use various BeautifulSoup functions to get all the proper text in all the fields? I tried using `soup.get_text()` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I see, you are getting JSON response, so you don't need BeautifulSoup to parse it:

```
response = requests.get('myurl', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}, params=params)
data = response.json()   # <-- note the .json() call

all_data.extend(data['data'])
```

---

Then, to get information from `shared` key, you can convert it to BeautifulSoup object:

```
for d in all_data:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(d['shared'], 'html.parser')
    # print only text from <p> tags:
    print([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in soup.select('p')])
```

Prints:

```
['Personal: Parents', '', 'KM:', '']
["It's great to see your clear."]
```

Comment: Thanks. My only concern/difficulty is doing this for multiple fields, so not just `shared`. Since this is a function that gets called, the fields are exactly known. I could add another loop so that I iterate through all of `d`'s elements - is that likely the only way to run this?

Comment: @simplycoding Yes, you can add another loop that iterates over d elements (`d.items`). Or you can only pick specific keys.